# Convert json file to prometheus metrics

Tags: json, tail, prometheus, telegraf

I have nginx json access log like this, a file that append sample like this to end of file.

```
{
  "time": "2019-11-27T08:23:39+00:00",
  "msec": 1574843019.787,
  "ip": "91.133.248.69",
  "agent_name": "firefox",
  "agent_version": "70",
  "agent_os": "linux",
  "agent_os_version": "",
  "agent_category": "pc",
  "agent_vendor": "mozilla",
  "agent_hash": "5c12a77e",
  "geo_country_code": "IR",
  "geo_latitude": "35.69610",
  "geo_longitude": "51.42310",
  "geo_accuracy_radius": "50",
  "geo_continent_name": "Asia",
  "geo_isp": "Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",
  "method": "GET",
  "host": "sample-host.tld",
  "request_uri": "/?mamad=1",
  "request_length": "218",
  "status": "200",
  "bytes_sent": "1777",
  "body_bytes_sent": "1672",
  "referer": "",
  "foreign_referer_host": "",
  "request_time": "0.006",
  "content_type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
  "brotli_ratio": "",
  "gzip_ratio": "3.44",
  "upstream_header_time": "0.004",
  "upstream_response_time": "0.004",
  "upstream_cache_status": ""
}
```

And i need to export metrics and tagged to prometheus the write way.

I write telegraf to read and process data:

```
[[inputs.tail]]
  name_override = "nginx_access"
  files = ["/tmp/access_logs.log"]
  from_beginning = false

  json_time_key = "msec"
  json_time_format = "unix"

  pipe = false

  data_format = "json"
  json_string_fields = [
    "bytes_sent",
    "body_bytes_sent",
    "upstream_response_time",
    "upstream_header_time",
    "brotli_ratio",
    "gzip_ratio",
    "request_length",
    "request_time"
  ]
  tag_keys = [
    "client_new",
    "agent_category",
    "agent_hash",
    "agent_name",
    "agent_os",
    "agent_os_version",
    "agent_vendor",
    "agent_version",
    "content_type",
    "foreign_referer_host",
    "geo_accuracy_radius",
    "geo_continent_name",
    "geo_country_code",
    "geo_isp",
    "geo_latitude",
    "geo_longitude",
    "host",
    "ip",
    "method",
    "referer",
    "request_uri",
    "status"
  ]

[[processors.converter]]

  namepass = ["nginx_access"]

  [processors.converter.fields]
    integer = [
      "bytes_sent",
      "body_bytes_sent",
      "request_length",
    ]
    float = [
      "brotli_ratio",
      "upstream_header_time",
      "upstream_response_time",
      "gzip_ratio",
      "request_time"
    ]

[[processors.regex]]
  namepass = ["nginx_access"]

  [[processors.regex.tags]]
    key = "content_type"
    pattern = "^([^/]+/[^ ;]+).*$"
    replacement = "${1}"

## output as exporter
[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
  listen = ":9273"
  collectors_exclude = ["gocollector", "process"]
```

And it's work and and metrics will be expose

```
$ curl -s 127.0.0.1:9273/metrics  | grep  'nginx_access'

# HELP nginx_access_body_bytes_sent Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE nginx_access_body_bytes_sent untyped
nginx_access_body_bytes_sent{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="10995fbc",agent_name="chrome",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="google",agent_version="78",client_new="0",client_uid="68d18ac1",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?arash=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 1415
nginx_access_body_bytes_sent{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="5c12a77e",agent_name="firefox",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="mozilla",agent_version="70",client_new="0",client_uid="54fde64b",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?mamad=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 1672
# HELP nginx_access_brotli_ratio Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE nginx_access_brotli_ratio untyped
nginx_access_brotli_ratio{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="10995fbc",agent_name="chrome",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="google",agent_version="78",client_new="0",client_uid="68d18ac1",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?arash=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 4.06
# HELP nginx_access_bytes_sent Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE nginx_access_bytes_sent untyped
nginx_access_bytes_sent{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="10995fbc",agent_name="chrome",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="google",agent_version="78",client_new="0",client_uid="68d18ac1",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?arash=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 1519
nginx_access_bytes_sent{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="5c12a77e",agent_name="firefox",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="mozilla",agent_version="70",client_new="0",client_uid="54fde64b",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?mamad=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 1777
# HELP nginx_access_gzip_ratio Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE nginx_access_gzip_ratio untyped
nginx_access_gzip_ratio{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="5c12a77e",agent_name="firefox",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="mozilla",agent_version="70",client_new="0",client_uid="54fde64b",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?mamad=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 3.44
# HELP nginx_access_request_length Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE nginx_access_request_length untyped
nginx_access_request_length{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="10995fbc",agent_name="chrome",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="google",agent_version="78",client_new="0",client_uid="68d18ac1",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?arash=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 387
nginx_access_request_length{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="5c12a77e",agent_name="firefox",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="mozilla",agent_version="70",client_new="0",client_uid="54fde64b",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?mamad=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 218
# HELP nginx_access_request_time Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE nginx_access_request_time untyped
nginx_access_request_time{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="10995fbc",agent_name="chrome",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="google",agent_version="78",client_new="0",client_uid="68d18ac1",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?arash=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 0.006
nginx_access_request_time{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="5c12a77e",agent_name="firefox",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="mozilla",agent_version="70",client_new="0",client_uid="54fde64b",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?mamad=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 0.005
# HELP nginx_access_upstream_header_time Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE nginx_access_upstream_header_time untyped
nginx_access_upstream_header_time{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="10995fbc",agent_name="chrome",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="google",agent_version="78",client_new="0",client_uid="68d18ac1",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?arash=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 0.004
nginx_access_upstream_header_time{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="5c12a77e",agent_name="firefox",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="mozilla",agent_version="70",client_new="0",client_uid="54fde64b",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?mamad=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 0.004
# HELP nginx_access_upstream_response_time Telegraf collected metric
# TYPE nginx_access_upstream_response_time untyped
nginx_access_upstream_response_time{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="10995fbc",agent_name="chrome",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="google",agent_version="78",client_new="0",client_uid="68d18ac1",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?arash=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 0.004
nginx_access_upstream_response_time{agent_category="pc",agent_hash="5c12a77e",agent_name="firefox",agent_os="linux",agent_os_version="",agent_vendor="mozilla",agent_version="70",client_new="0",client_uid="54fde64b",content_type="text/html",foreign_referer_host="",geo_accuracy_radius="50",geo_continent_name="Asia",geo_country_code="IR",geo_isp="Mobile Communication Company of Iran PLC",geo_latitude="35.69610",geo_longitude="51.42310",host="sample-host.tld",ip="91.133.248.69",method="GET",path="/memfs/default.nginx.access.log",referer="",request_uri="/?mamad=1",server_country="IR",server_dc="sample",server_hostname="sample-vm-nginx",server_type="vm",status="200"} 0.004
```

I need to know is my aprouch is correct, is there any misunderstanding?

And afther that how to collect Query per second(QPS) after these structure type.